# Logical operator XNOR in java

Tags: java, logical-operators

How to correctly implement XNOR in java?

I need both A and B to have the same value.

```
 XNOR:
 A  B   Out
 0  0   1   
 0  1   0
 1  0   0
 1  1   1

String someString = null;
boolean isA = false;
boolean isB = false;

if(someString == null){
    isA = false; // or isA = true;
    isB = false; // or isB = true;
}
if xnor(isA, isB){
    return getSomeMethod(isA, isB);
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `==`.

Comment: that is possible but is there an xnor syntax being used in java?

Comment: @dcdum2018 XNOR is logical equality, any operator other than `==` would be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `xnor` method like this:

```
boolean xnor(boolean a, boolean b) {
    return a == b;
}
```